# wpf Area Chart with Different Colors?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit, area

I a musing the MS toolkit charts and cannot figure out how to change the color of the areas.  I need to populate the chart dynamically which means I do not know ahead of time how many sections the area chart will have.

Here is the code I have.

```
var a = new AreaSeries
{
  Title = "a",
  IndependentValuePath = "Key",
  DependentValuePath = "Value",
  Background = Brushes.Plum
};
```

I have tried to change both the Fore Ground and Background and no dice.

```
mcChart.Series.Add(a);

a = new AreaSeries
{
  Title = "b",
  IndependentValuePath = "Key",
  DependentValuePath = "Value",
  Background = Brushes.Peru
};

mcChart.Series.Add(a);
```

Fill the chart.

```
((AreaSeries)mcChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = new[]
{
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("1", 100),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2", 180),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("3", 110),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("4", 95),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("5", 40),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("6", 95)
};

((AreaSeries)mcChart.Series[1]).ItemsSource = new[]
{
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("1", 150),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("2", 280),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("3", 310),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("4", 195),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("5", 340),
  new KeyValuePair<string, int>("6", 195)
};
```

I am new to wpf and I cannot figure out what is wrong with this.

Here is the XAML

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart 
  Width="600" Height="450"
  Name="mcChart" 
  Background="LightBlue"
  Foreground="DarkBlue"
  Title="Area Chart">                
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

How do I change the color of area a and area b.  Right now they are what ever color is default even though I set the background and foreground.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Chart.Palette` property like this:

```
<Grid>
    <charting:Chart>
        <charting:Chart.Palette>
            <visualizationToolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="MistyRose"/>
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </visualizationToolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
        </charting:Chart.Palette>
        <charting:AreaSeries Title="Series 1"/>
        <charting:AreaSeries Title="Series 2"/>
    </charting:Chart>
</Grid>
```

- [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/09/13/a-preview-of-upcoming-charting-changes-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-1.aspx) is some more information.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but how do you do this via code?  I will not know how many series I have until I pull the data from the db.  I have to do this dynamically.  Any ideas?  Thank you again.

Comment: The palette can arbitrarily long.  That is, it doesn't need to match the number of columns.  As long as you don't need to choose the colors at run-time, you can create one palette in XAML and use it in code.  If you do need to change the colors in code, just build it up, e.g. `new ResourceDictionaryCollection()' etc.

Comment: I still dont get which property is to be changed for changing the background of area graph?