# Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Property' to object of type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, charts, wpftoolkit

I have tab control one tab contains DataGrid second ColumnSeries chart when i press when i press charts tab i'm getting such error:

> Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Property' to object of type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'.
>   Failed to create a 'DependencyProperty' from the text 'Background'.

i don't have any event on tab control, this is my DataGrid:

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl1">
    <TabItem Name="tabItem1" Header="Logs">
        <Grid>
            <Grid Background="#FFABABAB">
                <Border Name="border1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Height="92" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="AliceBlue" Margin="0,0,1,0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Name="btnGridToExcel" Content="Export To Excel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="639,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Click="btnGridToExcel_Click" />
                        <Button Name="btnReset" Content="Reset/Refresh" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="639,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Click="btnReset_Click" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Margin="0,91,1,32" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectionMode="Extended" 
                          SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserReorderColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="false" CanUserDeleteRows="false" 
                          IsReadOnly="true" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF2F4F4" RowBackground="#FFE0E4E3" ItemsSource="{Binding ActionCollection}" 
                          SelectedCellsChanged="dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged" >
                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Name="MenuItemEdit" Header="Edit" Click="MenuItemEdit_Click">
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/H-Pro;component/Images/1314285611_edit.png"/>
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem Name="MenuItemDelete" Header="Delete" Click="MenuItemDelete_Click">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/H-Pro;component/Images/1314285495_dialog-close.png"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                            <Separator />
                            <MenuItem Name="MenuItemPayment" Header="Pay selected" Click="MenuItemPayment_Click">
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/H-Pro;component/Images/1314875051_money_dollar.png"/>
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RoomType" Binding="{Binding Path=RoomType, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Room" Binding="{Binding Path=RoomNumber, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Guest" Binding="{Binding Path=GuestName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Persons" Binding="{Binding Path=Person, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Check In" Binding="{Binding Path=CheckInDate, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Check Out" Binding="{Binding Path=CheckOutDate, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Room Price" Binding="{Binding Path=RoomPriceWithCurrency, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Inc. First Day" Binding="{Binding Path=IncFirstDay, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Discount %" Binding="{Binding Path=Discount, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Discounted Price" Binding="{Binding Path=DiscountedPriceWithCurrency, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Binding="{Binding Path=Rate, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Days" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalDays, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Services" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalServiceCount, Mode=OneWay}" >
                            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalPrice, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price in Gel" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalPriceInGel, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Paid" Binding="{Binding Path=PaidMoney, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Debt" Binding="{Binding Path=Debt, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Invoice #" Binding="{Binding Path=InvoiceNumber, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <DataGridRowsPresenter />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.Panel>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

and Chart:

```
<TabItem Header="Statistic">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Background="White">
            <Button Name="button1" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
                <charting:Chart Name="ChartGuests66" Margin="6,48,87,262" Width="862" Height="451">
                    <charting:AreaSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" Background="Red">
                    <charting:DataPointSeries.ItemsSource>
                        <Binding BindsDirectlyToSource="True"/>
                    </charting:DataPointSeries.ItemsSource>
                </charting:AreaSeries>
            </charting:Chart>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: What is the line causing the error and exception stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue is caused inside the areaSeries with Background="Red".  The DataPointStyle actually has the background.

Remove that temporarily and if it solves your problem then I think you want to access the DataPointStyle of your area series to set the background.

Check this out:
[wpf Area Chart with Different Colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676807/wpf-area-chart-with-different-colors)

Edit:  Removed my xaml example, as a direct setting in place of styles does work.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug in the Microsoft Toolkit itself.
http://wpf.codeplex.com/workitem/12865

I had exactly the same problem and now I'm going to try to remove the bug and recompile the toolkit.