# Not able to change WPF Toolkit Area Series background

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I am using WPF Toolkit Area Chart control. I am not able to change background of the Area Series to any other color. It just assigns color code #FFFFA500.

My XAML code is as below

```
            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Palette x:Uid="tt">
                <datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3EA0C0"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary>
                        <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF44C8F5"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Palette>

            <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>

            <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries Background="Black" x:Name="SecondSeries" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" IsSelectionEnabled="True">

                <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:AreaDataPoint">

                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"  Value="False" />
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />                                                                                                                                        
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:AreaDataPoint">
                                    <Button Name="pointButton" Content="{Binding}" Click="pointButton_Click_1" BorderThickness="1" >
                                        <Button.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>

                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Cursor="Hand"></TextBlock>

                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Button.Template>
                                    </Button>

                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" FontFamily="Rockwell" Title="Expenses" FontSize="14" >

                    </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
                </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
            </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Please help me out. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wpf Area Chart with Different Colors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676807/wpf-area-chart-with-different-colors)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a `Grid` within the `AreaSeries` control Template which has a style applied to it setting the background to a `LinearGradientBrush`.

In order to change the background of the plot area, add this style

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="plotStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Pink"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and use it as the Chart control's PlotAreaStyle

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Background="Black" PlotAreaStyle="{StaticResource plotStyle}">
```